# Logical question about the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F$ is any antiderivative of $f$, and $I=[a,b]$ then $$\int_{I}f=F(b)-F(a)$$

Okay So the main proof for this as follows :

Let $F_0,F_1$ be particular antiderivatives,
We have $F_1-F_0=C \ => \ F_1=F_0+C$ let $I_1=[a,x]$then since;

$$F_0=\int_{I_1}f$$ We have $F_0(a)=0 = > F_1(a)=C$

Then the proof is almost completed. But my problem is, if for any particular antiderivative $F_0(a)=0$ wouldn't $F_1(a)=0$ be the case, since what we did here was to use the definition of antiderivative, we could easily write $$F_1=\int_{I_1}f$$

Comment: I would personally start with $f(x)=F'(x)$ and use the limit definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not happen to any particular derivative. You did not pick $F_0$ to be any antiderivative, you picked the one that  evaluates the integral of $f$ starting from the point $a$, that is unique. In other words, you did not *only* used the definition of antiderivative, as you said, you picked a specific one.

Comment: Do you mean a function has only one antiderivative on the interval a,x for all x

Answer (score 3):

If $F(x)$ is ***any*** antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$, then the two functions $F(x)$ and $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ differ by at most a constant on that interval.  Therefore, we have

$$F(x) =\int_a^x f(t)\,dt+C$$

for $x\in [a,b]$.

Noting that $F(a)=0+C$ we have $F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, which for $x=b$ yields the coveted equality

$$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$$

for **any** antiderivative $F(x)$ of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.